EXT4 Partion Access Increasingly Taking Longer
My home directory lives on an EXT4 partition. A while back, accessing this partition started to be delayed (disk sleep) to the point now where it has become painful
It would appear to have something to do with the journalling, as the following process jbd2/sdb2-9 goes into disk sleep during these periods of unresponsiveness.
I have checked the drive's SMART status multiple times, and it's status is good.
I have also set the noatime, nodiratime flags on the drive in fstab, but that has made no difference.
Further information, the partition is encrypted.
Does anybody have ideas what is going on and how to solve this, or is it the HD is going to fail even though SMART reports good?
Here are some of the error messages from sudo dmesg
[    2.662286] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0xf0000 SErr 0x280901 action 0x6 frozen
[    2.662305] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[    2.662310] ata2: SError: { RecovData UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
[    2.662336] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[    2.662342] ata2.00: cmd 60/10:80:28:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 8192 in
                        res 40/00:9c:08:01:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[    2.662363] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }

[    2.983602] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 40 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2


Run sudo dmesg and view the displayed kernel log messages. Are there any I/O error messages among them? If the disk or its cable is failing, you are likely to see a lot of them.


please EDIT your post with the result of sudo dmesg 2) your disk is likely dying, make a backup and change.


If you have a spare SATA cable at hand, try replacing the cable first. It should be easy enough to test. If that does not help, backup all important data as soon as possible.


My home directory lives on an EXT4 partition

As such, you can (should) easily be able to reformat that partition.
Copy off all data from that partition that you care about to something else for temporary storage.
Make sure the root account is accessible for login and that the root account home directory is not on that home partition (it should be /root). Then reformat that partition, and copy data back.
Should you reformat it as EXT4, or maybe try XFS, and see if the problem disappears?  I don't know.  In any case, make sure the line in /etc/fstab is correct for the filesystem (i.e. change ext4 to xfs) if you format it as XFS.  And I think the UUID might change if you reformat it, nevertheless as long as the root account is accessible to login as all the little things can be taken care of after a reformat of the /home partition.
In fact you could simply migrate your /home/leoplaw folder to /leoplaw.
Unless /home is on a separate disk, then the accessing this partition started to be delayed (disk sleep) kinda doesn't make sense; if it's your one and only disk in your PC then disk sleep affects the entire disk (system) not just one partition.  Same with sata cable or sata controller on the disk, it affects the disk not the partition.  So for as easy as it would be and zero cost, for starters simply reformat the /home partition.  And then troubleshoot into whatever the jbd2/sdb2-9 process is.

the /home partition shares a SATA drive with a NRFS partition that is rarely used.
/root and all of the other OS directories are on a SSD. Sorry for the lack of specifics.
I will attempt the reformat option.

I created a new /home partition on the SSD and moved all of the config directories over to there and created soft links back to the original /home partition. My system now loads lickety spit, and I don't notice any disk sleep issues any more. In fact, in future when setting up any new machine, I will use this partition configuration.
